# What is the performance cost of DocumentSnapshot.data() method in Firestore web api?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a web application using firebase's firestore, one may keep the `DocumentSnapshot` object in a variable and call `data` method to retrieve data contained in the document whenever required, or call `data` method once and store it in a variable then use it.

Is `data` method simply an accessor function and does not have a dramatic impact on performance or should repetitive calls of the method be avoided?

In a specific use case, is there a good reason for keeping result of `data` method's result, its `id` and `ref` properties in different fields in a react component's state rather than keeping `DocumentSnapshot` instance itself?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing terribly expensive about a call to data().  You can [examine the source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore) yourself.